# redundant use of preposition

Tags: prepositions, redundancy

> "An opportunity for a complete positive transformation of your child for which you have always aspired for".

The above sentence appears on the board of a private primary school. I think the writer has made a redundancy in use of preposition. The sentence should correctly read as follows:

> "An opportunity for a complete positive transformation of your child which you have always aspired for."

or:

> "An opportunity for a complete positive transformation of your child for which you have always aspired."

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can use any of the sentences you wrote below. The one written on the school board is incorrect.

Comment: Don't believe Indian private schools! Most of them commit blunders! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right. I'm not sure if it breaks a formal grammatical rule, but it certainly sounds clumsy. I would even rewrite the sentence entirely:

> An opportunity for a complete and positive transformation of your child that you've always aspired for.

Even then I dislike what it's saying; it implies that everyone's child is horrible and in dire need of a transformation that only the school can provide. That's just a personal thought though, and has no bearing on the validity of the sentence.